# (:any) routing blocks 404_override routing

Tags: codeigniter, routes

I have these routes :

```
$route['default_controller'] = 'Pages/view/$1';
$route['product/(:any)'] = 'pages/product/$1';
$route['category/(:any)'] = 'pages/category/$1';
$route['(:any)'] = 'pages/view/$1';
```

but when I want to add `$route['404_override'] = 'My404'` my `any` routing stops working and I'm not able to get to my homepage like `base_url('home')...`

Comment: Of course, it's going to block it since (:any) will match anything so no page will return 404...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to define the route for home controller. Problem is that you have defined `$route['(:any)'] = 'pages/view/$1';` which will override all undefined routes. So either you need to change the `$route['(:any)'] = 'pages/view/$1';` to something else or need to define the route for home like: `$route['home'] = 'home_controller';`

Comment: @Pieter Cheers!